# Alphanumeric sorting according to ascending numerical value?

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, alphanumeric

I was wondering if there was a way, whether in VBA or Excel, to sort a list of alphanumeric characters in order of increasing numerical value?

For example:

Given the list of numbers:

- 40T1000
- 40T989
- 40T421
- 40T654
- 40T532

How can I sort them to read:

- 40T421
- 40T532
- 40T654
- 40T989
- 40T1000

Comment: Is there a consistency to the string?  XXZXXXX?  Is it always prefaced by "40T" or by 3 characters, or a letter, or ....

Comment: The string always takes on the form 40T------ (with the '------' signifying a varying number of trailing values).

Comment: Where there's a will, there's a way. Have you considered trying something?

Comment: I considered building something that would strip the prefix and then sort the remaining characters according to value, but I was more or less wondering if there was a built-in functionality for this. (I have about 3 days of VBA under my belt)

Answer (score 1):

With your data in column **A,** in **B1** enter:

```
=--MID(A1,4,9999)
```

and copy down.

Then sort cols **A & B** by **B**

Comment: One improvement I would suggest: make the formula =value(MID(A1,4,9999)).  It removes the "sort anything like a number prompt" when sorting, and clearly highlights anything that may have an invalid value (like a trailing character)

Answer (score 0):

You could just extract the last number part in another column and sort the entire range based on the values in that column.

For example, if your data is listed in column A you can then use this formula in column B to extract the last part of the string value. That is, the part to the right of the "T", no matter how many characters there are in front of the "T":

```
=MID(A1,FIND("T",A1)+1;LEN(A1)-FIND("T",A1))
```